# Gradle how to depend on the output from another project

Tags: gradle

I have a pretty complex gradle question which I have not been able to find an answer to so looking for some help.

I have `subproject-a` which compiles source code and produces a .jar file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies { ... }
```

Then I have `subproject-b` which takes the compiled jar from `subproject-a` and modifies the java byte code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'

configurations {
  transformer {extendsFrom implementation}
}

dependencies {
  transformer 'org.eclipse.transformer:org.eclipse.transformer.cli:0.5.0'
}

jar {
    mustRunAfter project(':subproject-a').tasks.jar
    mustRunAfter project(':subproject-a').tasks.javadocJar
    mustRunAfter project(':subproject-a').tasks.sourcesJar

    dependsOn    project(':subproject-a').tasks.jar
    dependsOn    project(':subproject-a').tasks.javadocJar
    dependsOn    project(':subproject-a').tasks.sourcesJar

    def baseDir = project(':subproject-a').buildDir
    def baseJars = fileTree(baseDir).matching {include 'libs/*.jar' }

    inputs.files(baseJars).skipWhenEmpty()
    outputs.dir project.buildDir

    doLast {
        new File(project.buildDir, "libs").mkdirs()
        fileTree(project.buildDir).matching { include 'libs/*.jar' }.each { delete it }

        baseJars.each { bundleJar ->
            def sourceJar = baseDir.path + '/libs/' + bundleJar.name
            println 'Source jar name [ ' + sourceJar + ' ]'

            def transformedJar = project.buildDir.path + '/libs/' + bundleJar.name.replaceAll( 'subproject-a', 'subproject-b' )
            println 'Transformed jar name [ ' + transformedJar + ' ]'

            def transformerArgs = [sourceJar, transformedJar]

            javaexec {
                classpath configurations.transformer
                main = 'org.eclipse.transformer.cli.JakartaTransformerCLI'
                args = transformerArgs
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use `subproject-b` in `integration-test` where I need it available at test compile/runtime time:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
  testImplementation project(':subproject-b')
}
```

This used to work until I attempted to upgrade the gradle wrapper to 8.3 (from 6.x)
Now I get the following error:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':integration-test:compileTestJava' (type 'JavaCompile').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/me/git/project/subproject-b/build/classes/java/main'.

    Reason: Task ':implementation-test:compileTestJava' uses this output of task ':subproject-b:jar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':subproject-b:jar' as an input of ':implementation-test:compileTestJava'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':subproject-b:jar' from ':implementation-test:compileTestJava' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':subproject-b:jar' from ':implementation-test:compileTestJava' using Task#mustRunAfter.

    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.
```

I feel like I am missing something here.

1. (1) feels like I'm tightly coupling these projects
2. (2) and (3) feel like they should be implied from `testImplementation project(':subproject-b')`

Is there something I am missing here?
How can I tell `integration-test` that it should be using the `jar` output from `subproject-b` and not the source code which does not exist?